# JQuery - trying to add path "/" to a function to add an active CSS class

Tags: jquery

I am using a tab menu navigation system with sub-menus under each tab, except that each tab links to separate pages (i.e., the tab menu is not one page with multiple tabs to show/hide content).

The below code will set/remove an active class to an `<li>` so that a tab is active when you are on that page or sub-pages. The problem I have is on first load to the site (the "/"), the main tab that's linked to that is not active. This is the code:

```
$(function () {
    setNavigation();
});

function setNavigation() {
   var path = window.location.pathname;
    path = path.replace(/\/$/, "");
    path = decodeURIComponent(path);

    $(".toptab a").each(function () {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if (path.substring(0, href.length) === href) {
            $(this).closest('li').addClass('m-menu__item m-menu__item--submenu m-menu__item--tabs m-menu__item--active m-menu__item--active-tab');
        }
        else {
            $(this).closest('li').addClass('m-menu__item  m-menu__item--submenu m-menu__item--tabs')
        }
    });
}
```

I tried doing `&&` on the `if` statement and checking for the pathname = "/" but I am getting the syntax wrong (or it's not possible to do this way).

What I want to do is on load of the website, to highlight that first tab as active. Any help is appreciated.

Credit for this "active menu item" code: https://www.infoworld.com/article/3304440/application-development/setting-an-active-menu-item-based-on-the-current-url-with-jquery.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're removing the '/' when testing with this code:

```
path = path.replace(/\/$/, "");
```

Replace it with:

```
path = path.replace(/(?!^)\/$/, "");
```

(This code `(?!^)` means that it's not the first character.)

Comment: Understood. Could you show me the code, using what I have, of how I go about that. I made the change you suggested and tried `if ((path.substring(0, href.length) === href) || (window.location.href == "/")) {…}` but that's not working.

Comment: Switched out `href` for `pathname` and it seems to have worked. Thanks.